# Whats the proper way to check to see if an entry in a db table is null?

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I have a sub that updates a form on certain occasions. Sometimes I need to update a form when some of the entries in my table will still have a NULL value. I used this code to prevent the sub from trying to fill the form fields with NULL data:

```
    If IsDBNull(CID.Single().Age) = False Then
        txtAge.Text = CID.Single().Age
    End If
```

But I am getting the error "Nullable object must have a value." when it tries to fill txtAge.Text. This method is working on other fields.

If CID.Single().Age is NULL then shouldnt it skip this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got ("Nullable object must have a value.") suggests that `Age` is a nullable object.

When testing a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) type for a value, use the `HasValue` property to see if it holds an actual value.

```
If CID.Single().Age.HasValue Then
    txtAge.Text = CID.Single().Age
End If
```

Comment: LINQ to SQL will convert fields from a database that allow null to a System.Nullable<T> type.  This means a NULL in the database is <code>Nothing</code> in VB or <code>null</code> in C#.  It will not be DBNull

Answer (score 0):

Compare it to dbnull.value as in

if row("value") is dbnull.value then do X